# django serializer grouping by value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a django orm queryset like this.

```
[{"id": 1,"type": "en", "name": "aaa"}, 
 {"id": 3,"type": "en", "name": "ccc"}, 
 {"id": 2, "type": "it", "name": "bbb"}]
```

I would like to change like this, grouping a list of dictionaries by type using DRF serializer, I tried many possible solutions but could not get the answer.

```
[{"type": "en", "data": {"id": 1, "name": "aaa"},
 {"type": "it", "data": {"id": 2, "name": "bbb"},
 {"type": "it", "data": {"id": 2, "name": "ccc"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In[1]: from rest_framework import serializers
In[2]: raw_data = [{"id": 1,"type": "en", "name": "aaa"}, 
  ...:  {"id": 3,"type": "en", "name": "ccc"}, 
  ...:  {"id": 2, "type": "it", "name": "bbb"}]
In[3]: class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  ...:     id = serializers.IntegerField()
  ...:     name = serializers.CharField()
  ...:     
In[4]: class MainSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  ...:     type = serializers.CharField()
  ...:     data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  ...:     
  ...:     def get_data(self, obj):
  ...:         return DataSerializer(obj).data
  ...: 
In[5]: MainSerializer(raw_data, many=True).data
Out[5]: [OrderedDict([('type', 'en'), ('data', {'id': 1, 'name': 'aaa'})]), OrderedDict([('type', 'en'), ('data', {'id': 3, 'name': 'ccc'})]), OrderedDict([('type', 'it'), ('data', {'id': 2, 'name': 'bbb'})])]
```

or easier:

```
class MainSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    type = serializers.CharField()
    data = DataSerializer(source='*')
```